# Encoding Issue? HTTPPost ampscript function response insert into data extension

Tags: api, ampscript, json, httpresponse, character-encoding

I'm using the HTTPPost ampscript function to send a Json payload to an endpoint and receive a Json response back. I get the OK response back, but the Json response contains Chinese, Japanese and other special characters. When I insert the response into a data extension, the non-english language portions are in gibberish. I think it is an encoding issue. I think the data extension is looking for the Byte Order Mark. I don't know how to fix this issue. Please advise.